# Class method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class-method

Is there such thing as a class method in Javascript?

***Example of class method in Ruby***

```
class Item
  def self.show
    puts "Class method show invoked"
  end  
end

Item.show
```

Comment: Not a `class` "method" per se, but check out ecmascript6's use of the actual `class` declaration: https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#classes

Answer (score 3):

Like so

```js
function Item() {
   // you can put show method into function
   // Item.show = function () {};   
}

Item.show = function () {
  console.log('Class method show invoked');
}

Item.show();
```

But better use object literal

```js
var Item = {
  show: function () {
    console.log('Class method show invoked');
  }
};

Item.show();
```

Comment: What is the most memory efficient?

Comment: @Cyzanfar: That's not necessarily the important question. More important is how you want to organize your code. Do you just want to create a "bag of methods/functions"? Then use an object. Do you really want to create instances of a "class" with a class method? Then use a constructor function (aka "class").

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this, but my personal favorite is:

```
function Person(name) { // This is the constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.alive = true;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

myHuman = new Person('Bob')

console.log(myHuman.getName())
```

Comment: Isn't this more of an instance method?

Comment: patbaker82, this is a class of which instances can be constructed.

Comment: That's not equivalent to the code example in the OP.

Comment: humanoid, The getName() function can not be called unless there is an instance of Person.  This goes against what the OP was asking for, which was a class method.

Comment: True. Sorry about that.